# Drawing people and computers

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I get this drawing? Could you give me a hand? I'm very bad @ tkiz

[image]

Starter MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,%
                    backgrounds,%
                    calc,%
                    fit,%
                    positioning,
                    scopes,shadows}

\makeatletter
\def\tikzsavelastnodename#1{\let#1=\tikz@last@fig@name}
\makeatother

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = {Triangle[]},
node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
% for labels inside node shape
inlabel/.style args =
    {#1:#2}{append after command=
            {node[inner sep=1mm,anchor=#1] at (\tikzsavednodename.#1) {#2}}
            },
% schemas' blocks
        atomic/.style = {draw, thick, fill=white, 
                         minimum size=1.5cm, drop shadow,
                         append after command= {\pgfextra{\tikzsavelastnodename\tikzsavednodename}},#1
                        },
            io/.style = {draw, thick, fill=white, circle, drop shadow},
                    ]
%---
\node[atomic,
      inlabel=west:$X_A$,
      inlabel=east:$Y_A$,
      inlabel=south:$A$,
      ]                         (a)     {};
\node[io,below right=of a.south east]   (zn)    {$Z_N$};
\node[atomic,
      inlabel=west:$X_A$,
      inlabel=east:$Y_A$,
      inlabel=south:$B$,
      below left=of zn]         (b)     {};
\node[io, left=of a]            (za)    {$Z_A$};
\node[io, left=of b]            (zb)    {$Z_B$};
%
\coordinate[left=of za.150]     (xn');
\coordinate[left=of xn']        (xn);
\coordinate[left=4mm of zn.150] (zn');
\coordinate[right=of zn]        (yn);
% lines connecting block A
\draw[->] (xn) node[left] {$X_N$} -- (za.150);
\draw[->] (za) edge (a);
\draw[->] (a.east) -| (zn') -| (xn' |- za.210) -- (za.210);
\draw[->] (zn') -- (zn.150); 
% lines connecting block B
\draw[->] (zb) -- (b);
\draw[->] (b)  -| (zn' |- zn.210) -- (zn.210);
\draw[->] (xn' |- zn') |- (zb);
\draw[->] (zn) -- (yn) node[right] {$Y_N$};
% outer block (N)
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node[atomic,inner xsep=0mm,
          fit=(xn) (a) (yn) (b),
          inlabel=south west:$N$] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I am little bit confused your MWE does not come even close to your picture you have uploaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried something out. Maybe you want to use `\usepackage{tikzpeople}`. You can start with this:
I found the code for the computers here:
https://texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-diagram/

```
% Computer diagram
% Author: Elke Schubert
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shadings,shapes.arrows,shapes.symbols,shadows}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% taken from: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-diagram/
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
    comp/.style = {
        minimum width  = 8cm,
        minimum height = 4.5cm,
        text width     = 8cm,
        inner sep      = 0pt,
        text           = green,
        align          = center,
        font           = \Huge,
        transform shape,
        thick
    },
    monitor/.style = {draw = none, xscale = 18/16, yscale = 11/9},
    display/.style = {shading = axis, left color = black!60, right color = black},
    ut/.style      = {fill = gray}
}
\tikzset{
    computer/.pic = {
        % screen (with border)
        \node(-m) [comp, pic actions, monitor]
        {\phantom{\parbox{\linewidth}{\tikzpictext}}};
        % display (without border)
        \node[comp, pic actions, display] {\tikzpictext};
        \begin{scope}[x = (-m.east), y = (-m.north)]
            % filling the lower part
            \path[pic actions, draw = none]
            ([yshift=2\pgflinewidth]-0.1,-1) -- (-0.1,-1.3) -- (-1,-1.3) --
            (-1,-2.4) -- (1,-2.4) -- (1,-1.3) -- (0.1,-1.3) --
            ([yshift=2\pgflinewidth]0.1,-1);
            % filling the border of the lower part
            \path[ut]
            (-1,-2.4) rectangle (1,-1.3)
            (-0.9,-1.4) -- (-0.7,-2.3) -- (0.7,-2.3) -- (0.9,-1.4) -- cycle;
            % drawing the frame of the whole computer
            \path[pic actions, fill = none]
            (-1,1) -- (-1,-1) -- (-0.1,-1) -- (-0.1,-1.3) -- (-1,-1.3) --
            (-1,-2.4) coordinate(sw)coordinate[pos=0.5] (-b west) --
            (1,-2.4) -- (1,-1.3) coordinate[pos=0.5] (-b east) --
            (0.1,-1.3) -- (0.1,-1) -- (1,-1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
            % node around the whole computer
            \node(-c) [fit = (sw)(-m.north east), inner sep = 0pt] {};
        \end{scope}
    }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mylabel/.style={text width=8 mm, align=center}]
        
        \node[draw] at (0,10.5) {closed room};
        
        \node[police,minimum size=1.5cm] (B) at (0,4) {Interrogator};

        
        \node[duck,minimum size=1.5cm,mirrored,good] (B) at (10,4) {User};
        
        filldraw (0,4) node [below] {center here} circle (1pt);
        \node [draw,dashed, very thick, shape=rectangle, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=10cm, anchor=center] at (0,5) {};

        \pic(comp0) [draw,scale=0.4,fill = gray!20, pic text = {Supercomputer}] at (-8,2) {computer};
        \node[draw,text width=4cm] at (-8,-1.5) {Supercomputer running an intelligent program};
        
        \draw[thick] (-3,4) -- (-6.2,2.5);
        
        \pic(comp0) [draw,scale=0.2,fill = gray!20, pic text = {something}] at (7,4) {computer};
        \node[draw] at (7,2) {T3};
        
        \pic(comp1) [draw,scale=0.2,fill = gray!20, pic text = {CAT}] at (3,4) {computer};
        \node[draw] at (3,2) {T2};
        
        \pic(comp0) [draw,scale=0.2,fill = gray!20, pic text = {DOG}] at (-3,4) {computer};
        \node[draw] at (-3,2) {T1};
        
        \draw[thick] (4,4) -- (6,3.5);
        
        \node[draw] at (0,-1) {T1, T2, T3: Dumb Terminals};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.. `+1` its awesome...

Comment: This is next-level, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Were lacking the keyboard ;)