# Adding a keyboard to computers

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I add a keyboard to the computers on the picture?

[image]

CREDITS TO [ROLAND](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573944/194319)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shadings,shapes.arrows,shapes.symbols,shadows}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% taken from: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-diagram/
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
    comp/.style = {
        minimum width  = 8cm,
        minimum height = 4.5cm,
        text width     = 8cm,
        inner sep      = 0pt,
        text           = green,
        align          = center,
        font           = \Huge,
        transform shape,
        thick
    },
    monitor/.style = {draw = none, xscale = 18/16, yscale = 11/9},
    display/.style = {shading = axis, left color = black!60, right color = black},
    ut/.style      = {fill = gray}
}
\tikzset{
    computer/.pic = {
        % screen (with border)
        \node(-m) [comp, pic actions, monitor]
        {\phantom{\parbox{\linewidth}{\tikzpictext}}};
        % display (without border)
        \node[comp, pic actions, display] {\tikzpictext};
        \begin{scope}[x = (-m.east), y = (-m.north)]
            % filling the lower part
            \path[pic actions, draw = none]
            ([yshift=2\pgflinewidth]-0.1,-1) -- (-0.1,-1.3) -- (-1,-1.3) --
            (-1,-2.4) -- (1,-2.4) -- (1,-1.3) -- (0.1,-1.3) --
            ([yshift=2\pgflinewidth]0.1,-1);
            % filling the border of the lower part
            \path[ut]
            (-1,-2.4) rectangle (1,-1.3)
            (-0.9,-1.4) -- (-0.7,-2.3) -- (0.7,-2.3) -- (0.9,-1.4) -- cycle;
            % drawing the frame of the whole computer
            \path[pic actions, fill = none]
            (-1,1) -- (-1,-1) -- (-0.1,-1) -- (-0.1,-1.3) -- (-1,-1.3) --
            (-1,-2.4) coordinate(sw)coordinate[pos=0.5] (-b west) --
            (1,-2.4) -- (1,-1.3) coordinate[pos=0.5] (-b east) --
            (0.1,-1.3) -- (0.1,-1) -- (1,-1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
            % node around the whole computer
            \node(-c) [fit = (sw)(-m.north east), inner sep = 0pt] {};
        \end{scope}
    }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mylabel/.style={text width=8 mm, align=center}]
        
        \node[draw] at (0,10.5) {closed room};
        
        \node[police,minimum size=1.5cm] (B) at (0,4) {Interrogator};

        
        \node[duck,minimum size=1.5cm,mirrored,good] (B) at (10,4) {User};
        
        filldraw (0,4) node [below] {center here} circle (1pt);
        \node [draw,dashed, very thick, shape=rectangle, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=10cm, anchor=center] at (0,5) {};

        \pic(comp0) [draw,scale=0.4,fill = gray!20, pic text = {Supercomputer}] at (-8,2) {computer};
        \node[draw,text width=4cm] at (-8,-1.5) {Supercomputer running an intelligent program};
        
        \draw[thick] (-3,4) -- (-6.2,2.5);
        
        \pic(comp0) [draw,scale=0.2,fill = gray!20, pic text = {something}] at (7,4) {computer};
        \node[draw] at (7,2) {T3};
        
        \pic(comp1) [draw,scale=0.2,fill = gray!20, pic text = {CAT}] at (3,4) {computer};
        \node[draw] at (3,2) {T2};
        
        \pic(comp0) [draw,scale=0.2,fill = gray!20, pic text = {DOG}] at (-3,4) {computer};
        \node[draw] at (-3,2) {T1};
        
        \draw[thick] (4,4) -- (6,3.5);
        
        \node[draw] at (0,-1) {T1, T2, T3: Dumb Terminals};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aren't those white trapezoids supposed to be keyboards?

Comment: Mmm not really, it looks like as if it was the cooling system. But we could add a mouse.